# Specialize the regex type re.Pattern

Tags: python, regex, types, mypy

Specializing the type of `re.Pattern` to `re.Pattern[bytes]`, `mypy` correctly detects the type error:

```
import re
REGEX: re.Pattern[bytes] = re.compile(b"\xab.{2}")
def check(pattern: str) -> bool:
    if str == "xyz":
        return REGEX.fullmatch(pattern) is not None
    return True
print(check("abcd"))
```

Type mismatch detected:

```
$ mypy ~/main.py 
/home/oren/main.py:5: error: Argument 1 to "fullmatch" of "Pattern" has incompatible type "str"; expected "bytes"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

However, when I try to actually run the code I get a weird (?) message:

```
$ python ~/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oren/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    REGEX: re.Pattern[bytes] = re.compile(b"\xab.{2}")
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

How come the type annotation bothers Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ability to specialize the generic `re.Pattern` and `re.Match` types using `[str]` or `[bytes]` was added in Python 3.9. It seems you are using an older Python version.

For Python versions earlier than 3.8 the `typing` module provides a `typing.re` namespace which contains replacement types for this purpose.

Since Python 3.8, they are directly available in the `typing` module and the `typing.re` namespace is deprecated (will be removed in Python 3.12).

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Pattern

Summary:

- for Python <3.8, use `typing.re.Pattern[bytes]`
- for Python 3.8, use `typing.Pattern[bytes]`
- for Python 3.9+, use `re.Pattern[bytes]`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `typing` module? I think the problem here occurs because `re.Pattern[bytes]` expression cannot be used like you want to.
Try something like `typing.re.Pattern[bytes]`.

[I checked it on python3.7 and it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mETOv.png)